# get the column from 2d array to calculate the normalization and cross product in python

Tags: python, numpy

I have a 2d matrix with dimension (3, n) called `A`, I want to calculate the normalization and cross product of two arrays (b,z) (see the code please) for each column (for the first column, then the second one and so on).

let say A is:

```html
A=[[-0.00022939 -0.04265404  0.00022939]
 [ 0.         -0.2096513   0.        ]
 [ 0.00026388  0.00465183  0.00026388]]
```

how can I take the first column( -0.00022939,       0.,       0.00026388) from A and use it in the function below, then take then second column, ... n column

```
def vectors(b): 
    b = b/np.sqrt(np.sum(b**2.,axis=0))
    b = b/np.linalg.norm(b)     
    z = np.array([0.,0.,1.])
    n1 = np.cross(z,b,axis=0)
    n1 = n1/np.linalg.norm(n1) ## normalize n

    return [n1] 

n1 = vectors(A)
```

How can I make a loop that  picks the first column and makes the calculation, then the second column and so on. Any help!!. Thank in advance

Comment: I suggest you add a sample matrix `A` and show the result you desire. Please clarify exactly what yo want. I don't understand.

Comment: @mr.bjerre, I have done this for the whole matrix I have, and it works, but I want to use the first  column, then second one,... until  n column

Comment: Again: edit your post with some clarification and an example (done by hand). I don't understand what you are having trouble with and I'm probably not the only one...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how you set up your array to start with. I like to use numpy arrays as I find the indexing easier to get my head around. I think the below code is what you are after. As you always have 3 colulmns it doesnt matter how long A is, you can just slice it into 3 columns.

```
import numpy as np

A=np.array([[-0.00022939, -0.04265404, 0.00022939], 
            [-0.00022939, -0.04265404, 0.00022939], 
            [0., -0.2096513, 0.],
            [0.00026388, 0.00465183, 0.00026388]])

for idx in range(3):

    b = A[:, idx]
    print b # call your function here
```

EDIT:: Full implementation showing the code & the output

```
import numpy as np

def vectors(b): 
    b = b/np.sqrt(np.sum(b**2.,axis=0))
    b = b/np.linalg.norm(b)     
    z = np.array([0.,0.,1.])
    n1 = np.cross(z,b,axis=0)
    n1 = n1/np.linalg.norm(n1) ## normalize n

    return [n1] 

A=np.array([[-0.00022939, -0.04265404, 0.00022939],
            [ 0.,         -0.2096513,  0.        ],
            [ 0.00026388, 0.00026388,  0.00026388]])

for idx in range(3):

    b = A[:, idx]
    n1 = vectors(b)
    print 'idx', idx, '\nb ', b, '\nn1 ', n1, '\n'

Output:

    idx 0 
    b  [-0.00022939  0.          0.00026388] 
    n1  [array([ 0., -1.,  0.])] 

    idx 1 
    b  [-0.04265404 -0.2096513   0.00026388] 
    n1  [array([ 0.9799247 , -0.19936794,  0.        ])] 

    idx 2 
    b  [ 0.00022939  0.          0.00026388] 
    n1  [array([ 0.,  1.,  0.])]
```

Comment: when I use the function in my code (vectors), in the loop you mentioned it gives the value for n1 and n2  only for the first column not for each column. Because I need to calculate n1, and n2 for each column?

Comment: @AL-Zetoun it works fine for me see the edit made in my reply

Comment: I get  the same the same answer as your answer when A  is (3,3)       BUT when I use A is (3,n) gives me the same value for n1 ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
A=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]

def getColumn(m):
    res=[]
    for x in A:
        res.append(x[m])
    return res

def countSomething(x):
    # counting code here
    print x

def looper(n): # n is the second dimension size
    for x in xrange(0,n):
        countSomething(getColumn(x))

looper(3)
```

Comment: Im trying to use your code, by substitute   function countsomething  by function vector in my code above, but  it doesn't work?  'def countSomething(b): 
    b = b/np.sqrt(np.sum(b**2.,axis=0))
    b = b/np.linalg.norm(b)   
    z = np.array([0.,0.,1.])
    n1 = np.cross(z,b,axis=0)
    n1 = n1/np.linalg.norm(n1) ## normalize n
    n2 = np.cross(b,n1,axis=0)
    n2 = n2/np.linalg.norm(n2) 
    return n1,n2 '